# script is written in perl but contains errors

Tags: perl

I would like to know how to get this form making script to work again , it was written in 2007 but now it containing errors that I will attach...

```
#******************************************************************
#************************* SUBROUTINES ***************************
#******************************************************************

sub replace
{
    my $text = shift;  #This shifts through the supplied arguments ($whatever_php, 'FORM_NAME', and $form_name)
                #This $text is a LOCAL variable.  Does not overwrite other $make_form_results
                #Shift starts with the first value.  If variable (as in $whatever_php) expands and goes through line by line
    my %words = @_;
    $text =~ s/$_/$words{$_}/g for keys %words;
    return $text;
}


sub replace_save_php #a special case
{
    my $text = shift;
    my @fields = map {$_->[0]} grep{$_->[0] and $_->[1]} @_;  #Checks to see that Field_name and Field_type exist --Grep statement and map to @array.
    for (@fields)
    {
         $_ = "$_='\".\$field_names[\"$_\"].\"'";
    }
    my $fields = join ',',@fields;
    $text =~ s/FIELDS/$fields/;
    @fields = ();
    my @negatives;
    for (@_)
    {
        if ($_->[0] and $_->[1])
        {
            push @fields, "'$_->[0]' => '$_->[1]'";
            if ($negatives{$_->[0]})
            {
                my @temp;
                my $count = 3;
                while ($count < scalar(@$_))
                {
                    push @temp, "'$_->[$count]' => '$_->[$count]'";
                    $count++;
                }
                push @negatives, "'$_->[0]' => array(".join(',', @temp).")";
            }
        }
    }
    $fields = join ',', @fields;
    $text =~ s/FIELDNAMES/$fields/;
    my $negatives = join ',', @negatives;
    $text =~ s/NEGATIVES/$negatives/;
    return $text;
}

sub replace_sql #a special case
{
    my $text = shift;
    my $replace = '';
        for (grep{$_->[0] and $_->[1]} @_)
        {
      next if $_->[0] eq 'redirect';
      $replace .= $_->[0]." TEXT,\n" if $_->[1] !~ /^date$/;
      $replace .= $_->[0]." DATE,\n" if $_->[1] =~ /^date$/;
        }
    $text =~ s/DATABASEFIELDS/$replace/;
    return $text;
}

sub replace_view_php           #a special case  (They're all special cases aren't they? ;^ )  )
{
    my $text = shift;
    $text =~ s/(<\/label>)\s?(<label>)/$1\n$2/g;        #MAKE LAYOUT MORE READABLE. NEWLINE FOR EACH <LABEL> TAG
    my @text = split (/\n/,$text);              #PUT EACH LINE OF TEXT INTO AN ARRAY SPLIT ON NEWLINE (\n)
    my @temp = ();
    my $selname = "";
    foreach (@text)
    {
        if ($_ =~ /<select name="(\w*)/) #SELECT NAME FOR POPUP & SCROLLING MENUS.
            {
              $selname = $1;
              goto go;
            }

      goto go if $_ =~ s/(<textarea\sname=")([\w\s]+)("[\w\s="]*>)/$1$2$3<?php \$result = chkdata_Txt(\$obj,"$2"); echo \$result;?>/;  #TEXTAREA

      goto go if $_ =~ s/(<input\stype="text"\s)(name=")([\w\s]+)(")([^>]*)/$1$2$3$4 value="<?php \$result = chkdata_Txt(\$obj,"$3"); echo \$result;?>"/;               #TEXT

      goto go if $_ =~ s/(<input\stype="checkbox"\sname=")([\w\s]+)(\[\])("\svalue=")([\w\s]+)(")([^>]*)/$1$2$3$4$5$6 <?php \$result = chkdata_CB(\$obj,"$2","$5"); echo \$result;?>/;   #CHECKBOX-GROUP

      goto go if $_ =~ s/(<input\stype="checkbox"\sname=")([\w\s]+)("\svalue=")([\w\s]+)(")([^>]*)/$1$2$3$4$5 <?php \$result = chkdata_CB(\$obj,"$2","$4"); echo \$result;?>/; #CHECKBOX

      goto go if $_ =~ s/(<input\stype="radio"\sname=")([\w\s]+)("\svalue=")([\w\s]+)(")([^>]*)/$1$2$3$4$5 <?php \$result = chkdata_Radio(\$obj,"$2","$4"); echo \$result;?>/; #RADIO-GROUP

      goto go if $_ =~ s/(<option value=")([\w\s]+)(")/$1$2$3 <?php \$result = chkdata_PopOrScroll(\$obj,"$selname","$2"); echo \$result;?>/g; #SCROLLING-LISTS-BOTH & POPUP-MENU
      goto go if $_ =~ s/(.*?)name='(.*?)'(.*?)datekeyup(.*?)dateblur(.*?)\/>/$1name='$2'$3datekeyup$4dateblur$5 value="<?php \$result = chkdata_Date(\$obj,"$2"); echo \$result;?>">/; #DATE

        go: push (@temp, $_, "\n");

    }

    $text = "@temp";
    return $text;
}


sub make_form #MAKE_FORM
{
    my @data = @_;
    my $return = submit(-name=>'submit form');
    $return .= '<br />'."\n";
    $return .= "\n".'<table>'."\n\n" if $bigtable;
    for (@data)
    {
        next if not $_->[0];        #Go to next iteration of loop if no "field name"
        next if $_->[0] =~ /^#/;    #ignore perl type comments
        if ($_->[0] =~ /^\w/ and $_->[1])   #Check that the "field name" contains valid characters and that there is a "field type" in array iteration.
        {
            my $field_name = shift @$_; #Get current field_name for iteration of array.  Shift removes it from the array and moves to next.
            my $field_type = shift @$_;
            my $label = $field_name;
            $label =~ s/_/ /g;
            $label = ucfirst($label);
            $return .= "\n".'<table>'."\n\n" if not $bigtable;
            if ($field_type =~ /^textfield$/)
            {
                $return .= Tr(td($label),td(textfield(-name=>$field_name, -value=> join @$_)))."\n";
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^textarea$/)
            {
                $return .= Tr(td($label),td(textarea(-name=>$field_name, -rows=>4, -columns=>40, -value=> join @$_)))."\n";
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^radio_group$/)
            {
                $return .= Tr(td($label),td(radio_group(-name=>$field_name, -values=>$_, -default=>'-')))."\n";;
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^checkbox$/)
            {
                $return .= Tr(td($label),td(checkbox(-name=>$field_name, -value=>'yes', -label=> join @$_)))."\n";
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^checkbox_group$/)
            {
                $return .= Tr(td($label),td(checkbox_group(-name=>$field_name.'[]', -values=>$_)))."\n";
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^popup_menu$/)
            {
                $return .= Tr(td($label),td(popup_menu(-name=>$field_name, -values=>$_)))."\n";
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^scrolling_list$/)
            {
                $return .= Tr(td($label),td(scrolling_list(-name=>$field_name, -values=>$_, -size=>scalar(@$_))))."\n";
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^scrolling_list_multiples/)
            {
                $return .= Tr(td($label),td(scrolling_list(-name=>$field_name.'[]', -values=>$_, -size=>scalar(@$_), -multiple=>'true')))."\n";
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^header/)
            {
                $return .= Tr(td($label),td(hidden(-name=>$field_name, -value=>$field_name)))."\n";
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^date$/)
            {
$date_field_exists = 1;
$return .= <<"START";
<tr><td>
<span class='text'><?php echo xlt('$label (yyyy-mm-dd): ') ?></span>
</td><td>
<input type='text' size='10' name='$field_name' id='$field_name' class='datepicker' title='yyyy-mm-dd last date of this event' />
</td></tr>
START
            }
            elsif ($field_type =~ /^redirect/)
            {
                #you could argue that this does not belong here and maybe more appropriately on the command line.
                #I just wanted to make it so redirect could be part of the template file and leverage existing functionality.
                @redirect = (@$_);
                my $formname = shift(@redirect);
                my $mainfield = shift(@redirect);
                my $field_constants;
                if (@redirect) {
                    my %temp = @redirect;
                    foreach(keys %temp) {
                        $field_constants .= "'$_' => '".$temp{$_}."', ";
                    }
                    $field_constants =~ s/, $/\)/;
                    $field_constants = "array('$mainfield' => \$data,".$field_constants;
                } else {
                    $field_constants = "array('$mainfield' => \$data)";
                }
#               my $t1 = "<tr><td><b>";
#               my $t2 = "</b></td></tr>";
#               my $t3 = "<tr><td>";
#               my $t4 = "</td>><td>";
#               my $t5 = "</tr></td>";
                my ($t1,$t2,$t3,$t4,$t5) = ('','','','','');
                $redirect_string = "\n}\n" .
#                   "\$data = \"<table>\\n\";\n" .
                    "foreach (\$field_names as \$k => \$v) {\n" .
                    "  if (\$k == \$v && \$v != '') {\/\/header\n" .
                    "    \$data .= \"$t1\\n\\n\".\$k.\"$t2\\n\\n\";\n" .
                    "  }\n" .
                    "  elseif (\$v != '') {\n" .
                    "    \$data .= \"$t3\".\$k.\": $t4\".\$v.\"$t5\\n\";\n" .
                    "  }\n" .
                    "}\n" .
#                   "\$data .= \"</table>\\n\";\n" .
                    "\$newid = formSubmit(\"form_$formname\", $field_constants, \$_GET[\"id\"], \$userauthorized);\n" .
                    "addForm(\$encounter, \"$formname\", \$newid, \"$formname\", \$pid, \$userauthorized);"
            }
            unshift @$_, $label;
            unshift @$_, $field_type;
            unshift @$_, $field_name;
            $return .= "\n".'</table>'."\n" if not $bigtable;
        }
        elsif (!$bigtable) #probably an html tag or something -- Get to this point if no Field_name and Field_type found in array.
        {

              if ($_->[0] !~ /<br />\s*$|<\/td>\s*$|<\/tr>\s*$|<\/p>\s*$/) {
                $return .= '<br />'."\n";
              }

              $return .= $_->[0]."\n";


        }
    }
    $return .= "<table>" if not $bigtable;
    $return .= "</table>";
    $return .= submit(-name=>'submit form');
    return $return;
}

#***********************************************************************************************************
#**Receive 'full file path' and '$out' (finished output) from REPLACEMENT SECTION above and write to file.**
#***********************************************************************************************************

sub to_file
{
    my $filename = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    my $file;
    open $file, '>', $filename or die "cannot open $filename: $!";
    print $file $string;
    close $file or die "cannot close $filename: $!";
}
sub xl_fix #make compliant with translation feature
{
    my $string = shift;
    return $string if $noxl;
    $string =~ s/(>{1,2})([^\s][^<>]+?)<\//$1 <\?php echo xlt("$2") \?> <\//gs;
        return $string;
}
sub xl_fix2 #make compliant with translation feature for report.php
{
    my $string = shift;
    return $string if $noxl;
    $string =~ s/\.(\$\w+)\./\.xl("$1")\./gs;
        return $string;
}
```

The above code is part of a script that makes forms and the error is starting with the line that has \s in it:

```
if ($_->[0] !~ /<br />\s*$|<\/td>\s*$|<\/tr>\s*$|<\/p>\s*$/) {
            $return .= '<br />'."\n";
          }

          $return .= $_->[0]."\n";"
```

indicating that it is "unrecognized escape" among other following errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5cjQ.png)

Comment: Please add the error text as text. And, one way to figure this out is to try to reproduce the problem in a minimal program. No one wants to read through a big dump of code.

Comment: `/<br />\s*$|...` - how could this ever have worked? There is an unescaped `/` after the `<br ` which means that the regex (started with `/`) will end there. Escape this and no more errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unescaped / in the `<br />` part:

```
$_->[0] !~ /<br />\s*$|<\/td>\s*$|<\/tr>\s*$|<\/p>\s*$/
```

Since you have many forward slashes in the pattern, you might want to use an alternate delimiter:

```
$_->[0] !~ m! ... !;
```

Also, you might be able to make the whole thing much simpler by reducing the repetition in the alternations:

```
 $_->[0] !~ m! < (?:br /|/(?:t[rd]|p)) > \s* $!x
```

This looks better when I spread it out and comment it:

```
 $_->[0] !~ m! 
     <            # start a tag
     (?:          # non-capturing group for tag innards
         br \s* /         # closing <br />
         |              # OR
         /                # closing /
         (?:              # non-capturing group for tag
           t[rd]          # td or tr
           |               #OR
           p              # p
         )
      ) 
      >            # end a tag
      \s*          # optional whitespace at end
      $            # end or newline-end
     !x
```

Comment: Is it possible Brian to point to the syntax errors I posted in the attached image, thank you.

Comment: I did. That's the unescaped /. But, get the errors as text and replace the image with that text.

Comment: I made the change and now I got this error:
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/ < ( <-- HERE ?:br // at formscript.pl line 766.

Comment: I can't see what you've done, so I have no idea what you did. As I said in the comment on the question, try it in a minimal program first to see it in isolation before you put it in a bigger program.

Comment: What happened I copied your line and it was pipe instead of ! after m I corrected that and we passed Lin 766.

Comment: There is the code where it is showing error in the last line:

my $filename = shift;
        my $string = shift;
        my $file;
        open $file, '>', $filename or die "cannot open $filename: $!";
        print $file $string;
        close $file or die "cannot close $filename: $!";

Error was:

String found where operator expected at formscript.pl line 791, near "close $file or die ""
 (Missing semicolon on previous line?)

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments please. Your best solution might be to hire someone who can do your task.

Comment: There's no insult there. You are just completely ignoring the feedback I give and this isn't a chat service for live debugging. It seems you need more help than StackOverflow is designed to give you.

Comment: The line that was edited by you Brian was the only thing needs to be done to run the script successfully, I ran it on perl.bot and it did run the script with no hiccups, I just have to see why it did not run on my local machine. Thank you again and you may consider this question answered.